# Make Java JScrollpane scroll vertically instead of horizontally

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I am new to Java and currently trying to learn it. I am working on a simple program to display a number of buttons on a frame. I also want to make the panel scroll vertically but instead it scrolls horizontally.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class GridView {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Buttons");
    frame.setBounds(30, 30, 300, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 4, 30, 20);
    Container content = frame.getContentPane(); 
    content.setLayout(grid); 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton button = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        panel.add(button = new JButton(" Press " + i));
    }
    content.add(panel);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.add(new JScrollPane(panel), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Can anyone tell me why my scroll is shown horizontally and how to fix it? Any kind of response will be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I am sorry. My question was incomplete. I want to make it something like this, but with vertical scroll.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 4, 30, 20);
GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0, 4, 30, 20);
```

If you want columns of component then don't specify the rows value in the layout manager. Just specify the columns and the components will wrap when required

```
//content.setLayout(grid); 
//JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel = new JPanel(grid);
```

You add the buttons to the panel so you need to set the layout manager of the panel. Otherwise the JPanel will use the default FlowLayout, which display all the buttons on a single row.

Comment: Thank you very much @camickr. I also tried your answer and it works well.

Comment: @Noel,` I want to make it something like this, but with vertical scroll` - and that was the answer I gave you, Did I not explain it didn't work because your panel was using the FlowLayout? Did I not show you how to add the GridLayout to the panel? Did I not show you how to have the buttons wrap at 4 columns (instead of 3 rows) when using the GridLayout? I gave you this answer before you edited the question. How does that not meet all of your requirements?

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding in here. I never said your answer did not meet all the requirements. Besides, I said it works well. I have just edited my question to make it more clear to others. Once again, I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

It shows horizontally because the buttons are added horizontally so the width of the `panel` exceeds the view port.
If you added the buttons vertically, by using a different layout manager, the scroll pane would show vertically. For example:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));  //or setLayout(grid); if you meant to use tge gridlayout for the buttons 
/*JButton button = null;*/ //never used
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    panel.add(new JButton(" Press " + i));
}
```

**Edit** to answer the edited question. See comments:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Display Buttons");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0, 4, 30, 20);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(grid);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
        panel.add(new JButton(" Press " + i));
    }

    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(panel);
    //by default scrollpane will appear as needed, vertically AND horizontally
    //to prevent it from showing horizontally :
    sp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    frame.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @c0der. Your answer works perfect. However, I made a forgot to say the other requirement. I have edited my question. I'm sorry for that. Anyway, thanks a lot sir.